# How to convert (latitude, longitude)column of strings into column of floats?

Tags: python-3.x, string, gps

I have a data frame that shows time and GPS coordinates, looks like this :

```
2019-02-15 15:32:00 55.652480   12.510514
```

I need to feed it to a function that looks like this:

```
import math

def haversine(coord1, coord2):
    R = 6372800  # Earth radius in meters
    lat1, lon1 = coord1
    lat2, lon2 = coord2

    phi1, phi2 = math.radians(lat1), math.radians(lat2) 
    dphi       = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlambda    = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)

    a = math.sin(dphi/2)**2 + \
        math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2)*math.sin(dlambda/2)**2

    return 2*R*math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))

for n in clean["gps"]:
    print(n)

    for city, coord in crimepoints.items():
        distance = haversine(n, coord)
        print(city, distance)
        if distance <= 500:
            print('alarm')
            print(distance)
            crimelist.append(city)
            crimelist.append(distance)
```

This function takes in data that looks like this:
coord = 51.5073219,  -0.1276474
two floats
So I used this :

```
clean["gps"] = clean["latitude"].map(str) + "," + " " + clean["longitude"].map(str)

2019-02-15 15:32:00 55.652480   12.510514   55.652480000000004, 12.510514
```

to put latitude and longitude in one variable.
The problem is that I can not turn the string into 2 float numbers that are in one variable now.
I tried many things like float(), ast.literal_eval(), map(float,test.split(','))but without a result.

I get this error at the harvestine function:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-190-84732733cea4> in <module>
     44 
     45     for city, coord in crimepoints.items():
---> 46         distance = haversine(n, tok)
     47         print(city, distance)
     48         if distance <= 500:

<ipython-input-190-84732733cea4> in haversine(coord1, coord2)
      3 def haversine(coord1, coord2):
      4     R = 6372800  # Earth radius in meters
----> 5     lat1, lon1 = coord1
      6     lat2, lon2 = coord2
      7 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code I am using the float helper function to convert float from string which is contained in a single variable:

```
sampleInp = "55.652480000000004, 12.510514"
def convert_float(inp):
    splitted_data = inp.split(",")
    return float(splitted_data[-2]), float(splitted_data[-1])
lat, long = convert_float(sampleInp)
print("Types : ",type(lat), type(long), "Values: ", lat, long)
```

Output:

```
Types :  <class 'float'> <class 'float'> Values:  55.652480000000004 12.510514
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks,  unfortunately, I get the same result when I try to feed it  into the haversine function:  ```def haversine(coord1, coord2):
----> 5     lat1, lon1 = coord1  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: I edited the question, because there is not enough space in comments. When I think about it maybe if I change the harverstine function to take 4 variables instead of 2 it should work. I will try.